# Given a smooth connected manifold $M$ with boundary, let $x,y\in M$, is there isotopy to identity sending $x$ to $y$?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Given a smooth connected manifold $M$ with boundary, let $x,y\in int(M)$, there is isotopy to identity sending $x$ to $y$.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Now consider $x,y\in M$ in general, is there isotopy to identity sending $x$ to $y$? Normally, this requires setting up differential equations defined inside an open ball which allow flow with support within the ball. Then via connectedness, one can see there is isotopy when $x,y\in int(M)$. It seems this is related to existence and uniqueness of solution of ODE with half open half closed intervals. Or was there recipe to bypass this issue?

Ref. Milnor, Topology From the Differentiable Viewpoint. Chpt 4, Homogeniety Lemma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It is clear that an isotopy can only exist when $x, y \in int(M)$ or $x,y \in \partial M$. Now let $M$ be the annulus $1 \le \lVert p \rVert \le 2$ in $\mathbb R^2$. Then $\partial M = S^1_1 \cup S^1_2$, where $S^1_i$ is the circle with radius $i$. Then each isotopy $H : M \times I \to M$ such that $H_0 = id_M$ has the property $H_t(S^1_i) \subset S^1_i$ for all $t$.

Now let $x = (1,0), y = (2,0)$.